# Ldap Authentication User filter in Hive: failing

Tags: hadoop, hive, ldap, ldap-query

```
I want to implement the restrictions in the LDAP authentication, only want a specific group to have access on hive. Below are the properties I have given in the **hive-site.xml**. But the filter is not working.
Kindly check the following code and help me out with this ?

**Hive Version: Hive 2.1.1
Release label: emr-5.4.0
Hadoop distribution:Amazon 2.7.3**
```

Below mentioned properties I have tried adding in the hive-site.xml but they didn't worked and login was unsuccessful. Without these I was able to login using ldap mechanism as only ldap server url and authnetication:LDAP was mentioned:

```
    <property>
         <name>hive.server2.authentication.ldap.baseDN</name>
         <value>ou=Root,dc=int,dc=domain,dc=com</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.server2.authentication.ldap.groupBaseDN</name>
      <value>CN=Groups,OU=Root,DC=int,DC=domain,DC=com</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.server2.authentication.ldap.groupFilter</name>
      <value>hadoop-admins</value>
    </property>


<property>
  <name>hive.server2.authentication.ldap.customLDAPQuery</name>
  <value><![CDATA[(&(objectClass=person)(memberOf=CN=hadoop-admins,OU=Groups,OU=Root,Dc=int,DC=domain,DC=com)))]]>
  </value>
</property>
```

Kindly let me know if you have faced the same issue.

**Error**:

2017-12-20T10:29:32,414 WARN  [HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-45([])]: conf.HiveConf (HiveConf.java:initialize(3768)) - HiveConf of name **hive.server2.authentication.ldap.groupBaseDN does not exist**
2017-12-20T10:29:32,493 ERROR [HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-45([])]: transport.TSaslTransport (TSaslTransport.java:open(315)) - SASL negotiation failure
javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Error validating the login

Comment: The link I referred are:
[link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/User+and+Group+Filter+Support+with+LDAP+Atn+Provider+in+HiveServer2)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is an inconsistency between the filter

> (memberOf=CN=hadoop-admins,OU=Groups,OU=Root,Dc=int,DC=domain,DC=com)

and the groupeBaseDN

> hive.server2.authentication.ldap.groupBaseDN
>         CN=Groups,OU=Root,DC=int,DC=domain,DC=com

I'm confident that if you correct the groupBaseDN, things should work.

Comment: Hi Ludovic Poitou, Thanks for your reply
I think that we can't use both the properties (customquery and groupBaseDN) together. When you is using customLDAPQuery, then there wont be any impact of using groupBaseDN.

CustomQuery is not working as it is not validating the user. But the LDAP filter query works when I use it directly for LDAP server via LDAP UI.

GroupBaseDN: I tried using this, but the error I am getting is as..

 HiveConf of name hive.server2.authentication.ldap.groupBaseDN does not exist

Comment: I think you've over read my comments... The error you reported in that the groupBaseDN doesn't exist, which is probably true since you've defined it as "cn=Groups..." whereas in the query that works, it's "ou=Groups..."